# xelatex or lualatex don't recognise arabic script

Tags: polyglossia

I downloaded this font to type some text in arabic in this site :https://arbfonts.com/al-kharashi-59-naskh-font-download.html.

I have this error :! Package polyglossia Error: The current latin font Al-Kharashi59NaskhVariants.ttf(0) does not contain the "Arabic" script!

My system Windows 8.1 MiKTex 2.9.
Any advice ?

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[locale=algeria,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Al-Kharashi 59 Naskh Variants.ttf}[Script=Arabic]


\begin{document}

\textenglish{Text in arabic :}


نَصٌّ مَكْتُوبٌ بِالْعَرَبِيَّة



\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems a very very old (1994) non-Unicode font.

Comment: I can't read your font page but some other google hits suggest that the font is *very* old, so probably it really doesn't contain the script.

Comment: I suppose this post must be closed. Thanks for all.